# Angular DataTables : Multiple data tables individual column filters are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Angular DataTables with Angular way, Multiple data tables filters are not working, only one table working.

I have two tables, and different API's data. Im trying to implement individual column filters. Only one table is working, second table unable to do filtering. Any suggestion pls...

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.datatableElementList.forEach(datatableElement=>{
    this.dtTrigger1.subscribe(() => {
      this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.columns().every(function () {
          const that = this;
          $("input", this.footer()).on("keyup change", function () {
            if (that.search() !== this["value"]) {
              that.search(this["value"]).draw();
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
    this.dtTrigger2.subscribe(() => {
      this.datatableElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.columns().every(function () {
          const that = this;
          $("input", this.footer()).on("keyup change", function () {
            if (that.search() !== this["value"]) {
              that.search(this["value"]).draw();
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-e129uz)

Answer (score 0):

I only take a rapid look to your code, but if you has several tables you need use ViewChildren (ViewChild get the first one). And you need use in ngAfterViewInit

```
@ViewChildren(DataTableDirective) datatableElementList: QueryList<DataTableDirective>;
ngAfterViewInit()
{
   this.datatableElementList.forEach(datatableElement=>{
           ..your code with each "datatableElement"...
   })
}
```